# Oracle Case when problem

Tags: oracle, case

I Have a table like fallowing

```
    work_id      group    effort
   -----------   -----   --------
       1           A        10
       1           B        5
       2           A        7
       2           C        20
       2           B         3
```

I need a case when query that returns like fallowing

```
   work_id       1.group   effort1   2.Group  effort2    3.group  effort3
   -----------   -----     --------  -------  ------    -------  ------
       1           A        10        B        5
       2           A        7         C        20        B         3
```

goups are grouped based on another parameter that in another table. But when i write my query like

```
case when <condition1> then group end as 1.group
case when <condition2> then group end as 2.group
case when <condition4> then group end as 3.group
```

...(Same for efforts as well)

it returns

```
work_id       1.group   effort   2.Group  effort    3.group  effort
-----------   -----   --------   -------  ------    -------  ------
    1           A        10        null     null      null     null
    1           null     null     B        5
    2           A        7         null     null    null     null
    2           null     null                          C      20                      
    2           null     null      null      null     B         3
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 6):

You are trying to write a `PIVOT` query.  If you're trying to use a `CASE` to do so (which implies that you are not on 11g where you can simply use the `PIVOT` operator), you need to do an aggregate

```
SELECT work_id,
       MAX( CASE WHEN <<condition1>> then group else null end ) as "1.group",
       MAX( CASE WHEN <<condition2>> then group else null end ) as "2.group",
       MAX( CASE WHEN <<condition3>> then group else null end ) as "3.group",
       MAX( CASE WHEN <<condition1>> then effort else null end ) as "1.effort",
       MAX( CASE WHEN <<condition2>> then effort else null end ) as "2.effort",
       MAX( CASE WHEN <<condition3>> then effort else null end ) as "3.effort"
  FROM <<table name>>
 GROUP BY work_id
```

Of course, you presumably don't actually have a column named `GROUP` in your table since that is a reserved word.

Answer (score 0):

Try to take the MIN() of each of your CASE statements.  If you can work this into a PIVOT, even better.